# I am using PyInstaller, I am also using Tkvideo. If I do no console the video does not play but, if I do show console the video plays as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller, I am also using Tkvideo. If I do no console the video does not play but, if I do show console the video plays as expected. I have no Idea why, The code for the video is

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
my_label = Label(root)
my_label.pack()
    
player = tkvideo(video, my_label, loop = 1, size = (width, height))
player.play()

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone have any idea why? The video that I wish to play is also downloaded at the start of this script.

Comment: does it output anything to the console?

Comment: @Matiiss No, It doesn't.

Comment: does the GUI itself open if you don't use the console (it just doesn't play the video)? or does it raise some exception (run the exe from cmd to check)? like are any exceptions raised if you run it without the console? also how do you download the video?